# Weird slowness when using Prisma to connect from local machine to Amazon RDS

Tags: javascript, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, prisma

I'm experiencing some unusual slowness, but only when using Prisma on a local machine that is connecting to a remote RDS instance.

The strange thing is, if I run raw queries locally on the remote AWS RDS instance, it's much faster.

If I run my Postgres server locally, there is virtually no difference between writing raw queries and using Prisma.

There's something weird about the specific combination of using Prisma locally and connecting to a remote RDS instance. Here are some rough benchmarks doing a create:

1. Local Prisma / Remote RDS: ~1000 ms (this is the problem)
2. Remote Prisma / Remote RDS: ~100 ms (weirdly way faster than using Prisma locally)
3. Local Raw Queries / Remote RDS ~100 ms (also weirdly way faster)

I'm using a standard DB connection in my prisma.schema:

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DB_URL")
}
```

I've debugged my connection / disconnection logic and nothing weird is going on there with like multiple connections / disconnections on query.

The only clue I have so far is that Prisma creates these transaction blocks with separate create and select statements and generally they are much more explicit and verbose than the raw queries I would write.

Comment: What does 'raw query' mean?  You take the query which Prisma generates, but use psql to run it?  You write the query manually and give it to Prisma to run?

Comment: Transaction blocks are not created with 'create statements'.

Comment: @jjanes raw as in submitting a comparable hand-written query using just the pg library. I went through testing a few different queries, incl upserts, creates, updates, etc so I may not have caught that the create doesn’t use a block.